# Is there any relation among function space and B-Spline(Basis-spline)?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations

Actually I am a M.Sc. thesis student in Mathematics(Pure Mathematics) and doing my thesis on function space but I have also studied  about B-Spline. But the problem is that if I want to insert the topics B-spline then I have to show that B-spline and function space are related in somehow otherwise in my thesis presentation and viva I will face a great problem from the viva board members. That is why I need a good and reasonable relation to insert the topics B-spline in my M.Sc. thesis paper. I want to go abroad for higher education and want to apply my mathematical knowledge in real world  problem  . That is why I want to solve the partial differential  equation and differential equation using B-spline.   **I am also learning about measure theory,banach space,hilbert space.**

Comment: B-splines and NURBS for a fixed set of knot points have a nice basis. In this context, you're working in a linear space of functions. You add a norm of some kind (often a max norm) in order to study approximation. Those are function space ideas.

Comment: I have learnt normed linear space and also learnt about max norm and many other. Please explain your answer briefly so that i can be able to give a resonable answer.

Comment: If you have a knot sequence $0=t_0 \le t_1 \le \cdots t_n = 1$ and a set of weights $w_1,\cdots,w_k$, then the corresponding NURBS "basis functions" are basis functions for a linear space of functions. A NURBS spline is $\sum_{j=1}^{k}\vec{C_j}B_j(x)$. For a fixed knot sequence and weights, perhaps you want to minimize an error of some kind in an approximation, where the error is defined in terms of a max. That's a normed space problem. Once you allow the weights and knots to vary, the problem is not just a simple linear problem any longer, but the framework is normed space.